# I have get error in jupyter noteboook Kernel Restarting The kernel for opencv_faces.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, opencv, detection, face

```
# face detection

import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread(r'C:\Users\drsri\Downloads\man.jpg')
cv.imshow('Group of 5 people', img)

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow('Gray People', gray)

haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\drsri\Downloads\haar_face.xml')

faces_rect = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1)

print(f'Number of faces found = {len(faces_rect)}')

for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
    cv.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)

cv.imshow('Detected Faces', img)


cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is the code and In the line

```
faces_rect = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1)
```

it gives the error by writing the above code

please find out the error and how to rectify this error in jupyter notebook

Comment: Is haar_face.xml in its current folder?